# Can i have test management tool named Xray while i have older one named Zephyr?

Tags: testing, jira, jira-plugin, jira-agile, jira-xray

In my project, test cases located in Jira Zephyr. I have some troubles with Zephyr as you know ( lack of preconditions for test cases, native support for BDD ...). So I decided to switch test management tool to Xray.

I haven't found any solution to migration my test cases from Zephyr to Xray.

After that new issue is:

Is there any problem if i install Xray to Jira account while Zephyr is staying on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those 2 tools are two different plugins for JIRA, so they can co-exists and be used in parallel (by the same or different teams).

In order to migrate data you have 3 ways:

1. Migrate by yourself (complicated)
2. Ask Xray to help you with the
       migration
3. Ask a 3-rd party consultant/vendor company to help you
           with this. Here are a few

   https://www.servicerocket.com/

   http://www.moveworkforward.com/

.. many more (just google)

4. Ask a consultant (me or somebody else)

Answer (score 2):

Both plugins uses the issue type "Test", so that's a problem. But you can configure anohter name for the issue type of one plugin, i.e. "zephyr test".